# Empty Div doesn't register CSS events in IE6

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have two elements that have the same event onmousedown.
The elements also have a Cursor: move property set in the CSS style.
The elements are empty, and need be be empty, or at least transparent, except for the border.

In IE 6 the only the border registers the cursor change or activates the javascript event handler. IE6 treats the empty div's like they don't exist. If you hover or click on the border, it changes the cursor and can activate the onmousedown event.

This is not a problem in FF... Anyone know what's going on?

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBvTL/)

Answer (score 3):

It's because IE6 *hates* web developers.

Make it happy by forcing the div to be non-empty, with a `&nbsp;` as content.

```
<div id="ie6-hates-you">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: I think that extends to Microsoft, since the IE series was, until IE9, a generation or two behind on JScript & HTML5 rendering.

Comment: I'm not going to religiously debate on how much huge companies ruin your development life.  But I can objectively state that IE6, without question, hates web developers with an intense fury that is equaled only by torrential hurricanes and nuclear fission.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion did not work. I even tried placing actual text inside the div. It worked when I hoved above the text, but not the empty surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

It works in ie6 if you remove `position:absolute;top:0;left:0` from both containers.

Add `float:right` to #container2 and you get the same layout.

Comment: I can't float the containers. They need to be absolutely positioned

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a container around the 2 divs and set it to `position:relative;`

```
<div id="test-container">
    <div id="container1"><div id="container2"></div></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#test-container{position:relative;width:300px;height:300px}
```

This works in ie6.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBvTL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

that is becouse the absolute positioning..

you must set the width to 100%

```
width: 100%;
```